# Irreducible Representations and Direct Sums

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

I am learning about representation theory, and my professor stated the following as a remark:

> Let $A$ be a $k$-algebra. Every finite dimensional representation of $A$ is a direct sum of irreducible representations if and only if for every subrepresentation $U\subseteq V$ there exists a subrepresentation $U'\subseteq V$ such that  $V=U\oplus U'$.

The backwards direction is easy enough; since one can show that every nonzero finite dimensional representation has an irreducible subrepresentation and then proceeding by induction, the result follows.

I was having problems showing the forward direction. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional representation of $A$. From the assumption, there exist irreducible representations $U_i$ which satisfy
$$V = \bigoplus_{i} U_i.$$
For any subrepresentation $U$ of $V$, consider a set
$$\mathcal{U} = \{\, U' \leq V \mid U + U' = U \oplus U' \,\}$$
and take a maximal element $U'$ of $\mathcal{U}$ with respect to inclusion. If $U \oplus U' < V$ then there is some irreducible representation $U_i$ such that $(U \oplus U') \cap U_i = 0$. Then $U \oplus (U' + U_i) \leq V$ from irreducibility. It contradicts to the choice of $U'$. Hence $U \oplus U' = V$ as required.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I see, I wasn't thinking of a Zorn's lemma proof, that was clever.

Comment: This can be done by Zorn's lemma. But since you are dealing with finite dimensional representations, you can prove it without the lemma.

Comment: Oh, yes. Thanks for the correction.