# Complete reducibility, in linear algebra and in topology

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, representation-theory, hilbert-spaces

Consider a representation $A(G)$ of a group $G$ in a vector space $\mathbb V$.

The following two definitions of the complete reducibility are equivalent.

Definition 1

A representation $A$ is called completely reducible if it splits into a (finite
or infinite) direct sum of irreducibles.

Definition 2

A representation $A$ is called completely reducible if any of its subrepresentations
has a complementary subrepresentation.
$$
~
$$

To check their equivalence, we address two cases separately.

- The case of an irreducible $A$:

On the one hand, an irreducible $A$ is a direct sum of irreducibles (though it contains only one summand, $A$ itself). So, by Definition 1, an irreducible $A$ is completely reducible.

On the other hand, the space $\mathbb V$ of $A$ has a unique complement, the zero subspace. Since the zero subspace is invariant under $A$, the restriction of $A$ to the zero subspace is a subrepresentation complement to $A$ in $\mathbb V$. So, by Definition 2, an irreducible $A$ is completely reducible, and the two definitions agree.

- The case of a reducible $A$:

If $A$ is reducible, i.e., contains proper irreducibles, the equivalence of the two definitions is trivial only in finite dimensions. To prove it in infinite dimensions, one has to invoke Zorn’s lemma.

QUESTION:

Will the two definitions remain equivalent (and, if yes, will the proof remain intact) if the representation space $\mathbb V$ is a TVS (topological vector space) and both the reducibility and irreducibility are understood in the topological sense (with the subrepresentations being closed)?

MORE SPECIFICALLY:

Are these definitions equivalent in Hilbert spaces (the subrepresentations being defined in Hilbert subspaces)?

PS.

The existence of complements in topological spaces is [a nontrivial matter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complemented_subspace). Sill, my question is not about the complementarity but about the equivalence of the two definitions.

Comment: For finite-dimensional representations this should be true; also for algebra representations, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/913994/irreducible-representations-and-direct-sums?rq=1).

Comment: @DietrichBurde I certainly agree with you., In finite-dimensional spaces the two notions of irreducibility are equivalent, because a finite-dimensional subspace of an arbitrary normed space is complete, hence closed. How about the general case, for group representations?

Comment: @DietrichBurde I presume G is a topological group.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Oh, got it:  you are suggesting to seek counterexamples. If suppose such counterexamples exist, and the two Defs are not equivalent, which of the two is regarded standard, if any?

Comment: According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semisimple_representation) it is Definition $1$, it seems. Moreover to is stated that both notions are equivalent, right?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Many thanks for the link! Where exactly in that article is it said that this is Def 1 ?

Comment: The first sentence:"also called a **completely reducible representation**) is a linear representation of a group or an algebra that is a *direct sum* of simple representations (also called **irreducible representations**).

Comment: @DietrichBurde I see. Thank you!